# Open Source WYSIWYG HTML edition native component for Android

Tags: android, open-source, html, html-editor, library

I have an Open Source Android app in which users modify portions of HTML content, for instance:

```
Lorem <b>ipsum</b> dolor <i>sit</i> amet, <font size="7">consectetur adipiscing</font> elit.
```

Instead of editing HTML directly, I would like to offer them the option of a WYSIWYG editor.

Requirements:

- Basic HTML edition: font italics/bold/color/size
- Must not crash on malformed HTML, it must fail gracefully, for instance fall back to HTML source code edition. (many users insert HTML via third-party apps or manually)
- Embeddable in my native layouts. Not a different app with intents/share/copy-paste.
- Native library. I would prefer to avoid JavaScript libraries, except if their integration in native Android applications is specifically documented.
- Optional: Links and images would be great, but not strictly necessary. Support for more advanced HTML would be even better.

Comment: I would recommend TinyMCE except that it is a JS library and IIRC it has a lot of browser specific code and doesn't have any (at least official - or quick search findable) android integration docs. If you don't find a good alternative you might consider it but it since it matches all your other requirements. (Sometimes I post something with one req missed as an answer but that seems like too important of a req)